# How do I get rid of this error

Tags: c

When I put it in the case statement as 1, I get an error
How do I get this to run and use case statements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int fib(int n)
{
   if ( n <= 1 )
      return n;
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main ()
{
  int n ;
    printf("Enter Number to Compute nth Fibonacci Series");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("\n%dth term of fibonacci series number is %d",n, fib(n));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Case statement for what?

Comment: What do you mean by "_case statement as 1_"?

Comment: I don't see a case statement at all. Or an error. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This code runs as expected.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Did you do copy&paste from the incorrect file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your `fib` function to use a switch statement, here is a possible solution:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    switch( n ) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            return fib( n-1 ) + fib( n-2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I get an error How do I get this to run and use case statements?* which use case ? There is no compile time error, only use case you didn't check is what if user entered `negative` value.

```
if(n>=0) {
     printf("\n %dth term of fibonacci series number is %d\n",n, fib(n));
}
else {
     printf("you entered -ve value \n");
}
```

Also compile the code with warning enabled flags `-Wall` like

```
gcc -g -O -Wall test.c
```

It warns you like 
*ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]*

```
printf("Enter Number to Compute nth Fibonacci Series");
int ret = scanf("%d",&n);/* always check the return 
                             value of predefined function */
```